# Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write flutter project in mac os

Tags: flutter

Launching lib/main.dart on SM A505F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception: null. The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.